# Extreme url Path

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I need your help.
I have this link: `https://domen.org/bbb/bb/bb/uniqueID`
the link may change, but the unique id is always at the end
I'm use: `window.location.pathname.split('/')[2]`
but since the length of the link changes, I can't catch it all the time, how can I optimize this?
I only need to get the last link ID example: `https://domen.org/bb/uniqueID`

Comment: `const id = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop()`?

Comment: Note: nodeJs doesn't have a `window`.

Comment: @Andy, yeah sorry, thanks reply

Comment: What is “extreme” about this? How is this related to optimization?

Comment: @SebastianSimon, I don't know